# How do I process each five words in a text file in Java?

Tags: java, text-files

Greetings All;

I have a text file say "test.txt" and I want to make process on each 5 words only.

for example if the test.txt contain:

`On the Insert tab the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document.`

I want to take the first five words: `On the Insert tab the`, do some functions on them. then the next five words`galleries include items that are`,do functions...etc until the end of the file.

I want to do that with java.Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word groups of 5, then loop over the found matches.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w*\\s?){5}");
String s = "On the Insert tab the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document.";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
   String words_group = m.group();
   System.out.println(words_group);
}
```

To split the words_group you can:

```
words_group.split(" "); // returns String[]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.How do i implement it to loop for every group of 5 words.

Comment: The `while` will loop every matched group. Each group will be a string of 5 words cut from the working string. If you need to then loop the string of 5 grouped words, you can split on whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

So this pseudo code:

- Read the file
- Put the words in a list
- while( remain unprocessed items )

  - Take five
  - processThem
- repeat

Could be implemented along the lines.

```
String fileContent = readFile("test.txt");
List<String> words = splitWordsIntoList( fileContent );
int n = 0;
List<String> five = new ArrayList<String>();
for( String word : words ) { 
  if( n++ < 5 ) { 
     five.add( word );
  } else { 
      n = 0 ;
      process( five );
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you call `five.removeAll ()` in the else block after `process (five);`?

Comment: thank you for your reply,But would you clarify your code a little bit.

Comment: @user unknown: Indeed!... @Daisy, Hardly. I think this is as clear as it gets because I'm not attempting to do your work for you. You have to show us what you have so far and **what** do yo need help with. This is not *Do my homework*  site. Sorry

Comment: I know that it is not "Do my homework site". Thank you for your kind reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the String.split() method in the SDK.  Probably gets you a good ways where you're heading.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the whole text file into a single string and use a string tokenizer to create an array of words as long as your words of interest were always separated by spaces.